# Discord.js grab mentioned user for text

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

Okay so I'm trying to grab a user that was mentioned for this bot I'm making (harry potter themed)
and I want my bot to grab the user that was mentioned in the command and paste it's output to text so the bot will mention the target user I've looked over a couple of ways to do so and just can't find the right way probably leaving something out here chuck id undefined error.

```
async run(message, args) {
    var mention = message.mentions.users.first().id
    var expell = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
if (expell < 50)
message.reply('Target was hit by Expelliarmus and is disarmed.<@{mention}>')
else if (expell < 70)
message.reply('the spell was blocked.<@{mention}>')
else
message.reply('Missed target completely')

}

}
```

Comment: looks like your message has no users mentioned. 

try debugging the 'message.mentions' object before. 

to avoid the error user default value for first user - `(message.mentions.uses.first() || {}).id`

Comment: it is no longer throwing an error but doesn't seem to fill out the {mention} just says it like it is

Comment: Try `Target was hit by Expelliarmus and is disarmed.<@${mention}>`

Comment: @ViridianZe, Target was hit by Expelliarmus and is disarmed. <@${mention}> is what the bot is saying hmmmm

Comment: just doesn't want to pick the mention up as anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.users` property returns a `Collection<Snowflake, User>`. This extends upon `Map`. `.id` isn't a property or function of `Map` object's `first()`. You can actually just mention a user by putting their `User` object in the string.

Also if trying to access the user object by providing the ID is useless when you are already calling `.first()`. The function gives you the first `User` on the Collection without having to give it a key. The correct method of doing that was:

`var mention = message.mentions.users.get(id)`

Also, consider this:

**.users**

***Any users that were mentioned
Order as received from the API, not as they appear in the message content***

Type: `Collection<Snowflake, User>`

It's not guaranteed that `.first()` is actually going to be the most recent mention if there's by chance multiple mentions in a message, so you'll have to figure out how you want to approach that.

*What you wanted by the way was:*

I realize you were just putting the `id` in the string but this is how I'd do it. It's neater to me.

```
async run(message, args) {
// store the first User object on the Map in variable mention
var mention = message.mentions.users.first()
var expell = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    if (expell < 50)
     message.reply(`Target was hit by Expelliarmus and is disarmed.${mention}`)
    else if (expell < 70)
     message.reply(`The spell was blocked.${mention}`)
    else
     message.reply('Missed target completely')

}

}
```

Comment: Thank you for that makes much more sense now *facepalm*ing so hard +1 to this answer